# save as File download dialog not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, jquery-ui

I am facing problem.My save as dialog not working in chrome.But that working file in IE ask for open or save file.But in chrome it default open the Download location.I want different location,even i checked "ask before download file" checkbox of google chrome.My file created dynamic on page,so i donot use "TransmitFile" attribute of "HttpResponse class".

byte[] csvFile = returing value from DB;

```
       Response.ContentType = "text/csv";


        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + GetNoExtensionFileName(fileName) + ".csv");

     Response.BinaryWrite(csvFile);
       // Response.TransmitFile();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, which clears the buffer first, uses double quotes to allow for spaces within the filename, adds the content length, flushes the buffer and ends the stream:

```
byte[] csvFile = ...;

Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/csv";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
    "attachment; filename=\"" + GetNoExtensionFileName(fileName) + ".csv\"");
Resopnse.AddHeader("Content-Length", csvFile.Length.ToString());
Response.BinaryWrite(csvFile);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```